# How test Post request with custom object in content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: spring-boot, mockmvc, spring-test-mvc

I have controller:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/value/", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public String updateSettings(final Dto dto) {
        System.out.println(">>> " + dto);
        return "template";
    }
```

**Controller works if I send request across chrome window.** But when I write test for this method I get problem. Not converted object, value not inserted.

Test:

```
@Test
    @WithMockUser(username = FAKE_VALID_USER, password = FAKE_VALID_PASSWORD)
    public void test_B_CreateDtoWithValidForm() throws Exception {

        final Dto dto = new Dto();
               dto.setId("value");
               dto.setEnabled("true");

        this.mockMvc.perform(post(URL_SET_PROVIDER_SETTINGS)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
                .content(dto.toString()))
                    .andDo(print());
  }
```

> Output is >>> Dto{id=null, enabled=false}

How test Post request with custom object in content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case you don't need to use `content`, but instead you need to use `param` in this way:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(post(URL_SET_PROVIDER_SETTINGS)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
            .param("id", "value")
            .param("enabled", "true"))
            .andDo(print());
```

Comment: BEWARE this answer may be old ... it's not working for me. `Cannot resolve method .param in BodyBuilder`

Seems fine! ... just make sure you are using `MockMvcRequestBuilders.post` ... apparently that was the problem on my code.